# centering text in common lisp

Tags: lisp, printing, common-lisp, center

I have a string that I would like to print . Is it possible to center it when printing ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the ~< formatting directive.  This will return "hello there" centered within 70 columns.

```
(format nil "~70:@<~A~>" "hello there")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me in the direction of other examples of format?

Comment: Here is the Hyperspec section on `format`:

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm

Comment: Seibel also has some examples: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html